# VPC Service Control for GCR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, google-vpc

The VPC-SC supported products page enlists the following repositories to be available to all the projects

https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products#registry

However, seems the gcr.io/google-appengine is available too?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that either gcr.io/google-appengine is not available to every project or the documentation needs a refresh. I asked the maintainers of the documentation for clarification.

Thanks for pointing this out.

I’ll update this answer once the team replies.